# How to check if a matrix is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

So I have this matrix

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 1 & -6 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Finding Nul(A+2Id) gives me

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 3 & -6 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

On the answers sheet it says to solve the homogeneous system associated with A + 2Id which gives us

Nul(A+2Id)=Span $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I am completely lost on how to find the Span Nul(A+2Id)=Span $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -1  \\
    1 & 1  \\
    1 & 0  \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Can somebody please help me with the steps in order to get to this solution ?

Moreover, on the answers sheet is states

Since the dimension of the eigenspace E(λ1) is equal to 2 we observe that the ma- trix A is diagonalizable.

How do i know from this solution that the eigenspace E(λ1) is equal to 2?

Thanks!

Comment: You've already posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3021268/how-to-check-if-a-matrix-is-diagonizable)

Comment: Nope I haven't :) Please don't comment if you don't read the question properperly. This is a continuation and my question is different from the one before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $\dim E_{-2}=2$ because you computed $\operatorname{Nul}(A+2\operatorname{Id})$ and it turned out  that it has dimension $2$: it is spanned by two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: How do i know that it turned out to have dimension 2 and that it is spanned by two linearly independent vectors? Where are the two vectors (1,1,1)  and (-1,1,0) coming from ? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What operations do i need to do in order to find these two vectors?

Comment: You solve the equation$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\3&3&-6\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$and you see that its solutions are precisely the linear combinations of $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,-1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!! You are great ...Last question , if (1,1,1) and (1,-1,0) were not linearly independent, what would happen?

Comment: Then $\dim E_{-2}=1$.

Comment: E-2=1 because only 1 would be indpendent?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is an eigen value, then $\dim E_\lambda\geqslant1$. Since it can't be $2$, it is $1$.